# As can I remember administrator rights in java program?

Tags: java, windows, admin-rights

I'm launching my Java application with admin rights using manifest file and launch4j program to create an executable file, but in every execution is asking for admin password, and I will like that ask for password only fist time and remember admin rights for future execution. Also I install application with NSIS.

I use this manifest file and I run NSIS installer with admin rights so I can try to resolve this problem with manifest or with NSIS script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<security>
<requestedPrivileges>
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"   uiAccess="False" />
</requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

With this solution application run well but I would like that user don`t have to introduce admin password on every execution. Is that possible? Thanks for help

Comment: You could try to install your application as a service which runs under a specific user. I assume that most of the os should have the functionally for this. So I don't know much about NSIS, but there seems to be a plugin for that.

Comment: Sorry but I don´t know what you want say. I need my app execute with admin rights but for normal user on Windows platform.

Comment: Some program are installed as a service under windwos (for example a mysql server). Sometimes they run under a different users. That implies they have the capabilities to store user credentials. Services can run for all users depending on their configuration. For a general explanation refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service